# Size image to full width in liquid website layout

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I run a web-site with a liquid layout. It has a full width header, a fixed width left part, an optional fixed width right column and a variable width content area in between. I'm searching for a way to scale an image to the full width of the content div.

The general layout structure for the content is:

```
body{position:absolute;width:100%},div#content{position:absolute;left:300px;},div#article
```

I want an image within `div#article` to scale to the width `div#article` scaled without that image. Using `img{width:100%;}` does not do the trick. `div#arcticle` will expand to the natural width of the image and add scrollbars to the viewport.

I currently solve the problem using jQuery to scale the image to the container width, after the page has been rendered. However, this would require additional code, if the browser window resizes.

Is there a CSS solution for this issue?

If not, does anyone have a good idea to solve the resizing event problem in JavaScript?

Comment: Use `box-sizing: 'border-box'` and stop with the absolute positioning.

Comment: Please include a JSFiddle with relevant problem code. Thanks.

Comment: @AlienWebguy yes, looks promising for a redesign of the website. But are you sure it will solve the core issue, i.e. scaling an image to the final width of a liquid container? In this case, could you please hint why?

Comment: @iambriansredd there is no problem code yet. When you shrink the browser the liquid div should shrink. But since it contains a fixed size image, the browser will scroll instead. So onResize you could shrink the image to minimum have the div resize and then resize the image to the div. Not sure how exactly this can be done, but it neither sounds efficient to me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you need JavaScript but here's a possible CSS solution that uses background-size: cover which will fill your div.

```
body {
display: table;
width: 100%;
height: auto;
padding: 100px 0;
text-align: center;
color: #fff;
background: url(path to image) no-repeat bottom center scroll;
background-color: #000;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

}

Comment: This will put a background to the body. My images are part of the page content and as a block element shall fill the width of their parent div.